# How to find integer value of specific characters in a Java string array?

Tags: java

I am using the following code to take a string value like 9s or 4c that is located within a string array and find just the integer value of the first character. I would also like to be able to use this for string values with multiple numbers like 10s or 13c.

```
total = total + Integer.parseInt(a[i].substring(0)) + 1;
```

This gives me a number format exception. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: a[i].substring(0) will return all the String, if you just want the number, `a[i].substring(0,a[i].length-1)`

Comment: @user2519990 please accept one of these answers as a correct answer,if one of these helpful to you

Answer (score 5):

This will work

```
public static void getIntVal()  {
    String text = "123cc";
    String numOnly = text.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
    int numVal = Integer.valueOf(numOnly);
    System.out.println(numVal);
}
```

IF some one want to use as double, you can do it as follows

```
    String text = "123.0114cc";
    String numOnly = text.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}","");
    double numVal = Double.valueOf(numOnly);
    System.out.println(numVal);
```

Comment: if it is decimal value your logic failed

Comment: @shreyanshjogi if you are dealing with double you can use this code
         String text = "123.0cc";
        String numOnly = text.replaceAll("\\D+.", "");
        double numVal = Double.valueOf(numOnly);
        System.out.println(numVal);

Comment: @Ruchira That's just wrong. What if your input was `"123.0743cc"`?!

Comment: @zEro Thanks for pointing out me.Check my edited answer. It will solve your issue.

Comment: @Ruchira +1 for correcting promptly. But, may be, I deserve the +1. :P

Comment: sure, why not. i will give you +1

Answer (score 4):

`str.substring(0)` is just `str` again (read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)). You are probably looking for

```
a[i].substring(0, a[i].length() - 1)  // cuts off last character
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruchira's solution prescribes removal of non digit characters; which in your setup seems right. However, her solution is invalid if the numbers are floats or doubles as `shreyansh jogi` questions.

Implementing Ruchira's thought solution properly, this would solve your problem...

```
String text = "123.0121cc";
String numOnly = text.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}", "");
```

If you know what to expect, say `double`:
    double numVal = Double.valueOf(numOnly);
    System.out.println(numVal);

Otherwise.. if you don't know whether the rest of the text is `integer` or `double`, this would help you:

```
if(numOnly.contains(".")) {
    double numVal = Double.valueOf(numOnly);
    System.out.println(numVal);
} else {
    int numVal = Integer.valueOf(numOnly);
    System.out.println(numVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = total + Integer.parseInt(a[i].substring(0,a[i].length()-1));
```